# Best way to restart python script if it ends? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

I have a few Discord bots written in Python that will stop for whatever reason after a few hours. I want a way to monitor them and restart them if they go down. I've already looked for a few solutions including a bash script, crontab, and systemd, but none of them seem to be working for me.

Even with a simple while true bash script, it will go down for some reason. The crontab won't run because of what I assume are environment issues, and apparently systemd is only for services?

All of the python scripts are located in
    /home/username/folder/script.py

I would also like to be able to easily pause the service that restarts the scripts, because occasionally I will have to update the code with git.

Comment: Show your Bash script and explain how it fails, does it print anything, etc.

Comment: @JohnZwinck
    while true; do
        nohup python3 script.py >> script.out
    done &

That was the script that I just used to test if it would stay up. However after a day the bot still went down and there were no error messages in the .out file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my problem with systemd.

First navigate to:

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

Then create a new service as root:

```
sudo nano example.service
```

Make your service file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restarts example.py if it closes

[Service]
User=your username
WorkingDirectory=/directory/of/script
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /directory/of/script/example.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then type this in to have systemd reload the service files.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then you can start your service:

```
sudo systemctl start example.service
```

Finally, check the status of your service:

```
sudo systemctl status example.service
```

Comment: It may be useful to link to the documentation for this.

Comment: If you want to pause the script, I would suggest changing `Restart=always` to `Restart=on-failure`. Also look into setting up a watchdog in the service and have the discord bot feed it. A watchdog handles cases of the discord bot not responding, but technically still active/alive.

Answer (score 0):

monit will suit your needs, you can configure it to monitor your python scripts and  restart them upon failure.

it's kinda quick to configure

Reference : 
https://mmonit.com/monit/